# Add BOM stamp in xml by php

Tags: php, xml, fopen, byte-order-mark

I am completing my project on fusion chart. I need to add BOM  signature in my dynamic xml. But I am unable to figure out that how can I add BOM signature for dynamic xml using php.
My codes are like this

```
$filename="a.xml";
$file= fopen("$filename", "w");
$_xml="<something/>";
fwrite($file, $_xml);
fclose($file);
```

In fusion chart documentation I found I need to add for general php output

```
header ( 'Content-type: text/xml' );
echo pack ( "C3" , 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf );
```

So can any one help me with this? 
Thank you,

Comment: What is the charset/encoding your file uses?

Comment: Are you writing in utf-16 mode? A BOM is not necessary (and recommended against) for UTF-8 output.

Comment: @Marc B I am not writing in utf-16

Comment: @DAKSH: ANSI has no BOM, see my answer which encoding forms have a BOM.

Comment: @Marc B: Not that I want recommend it, but you can use the BOM to specify the file is in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BOM as a signature no matter how the Unicode text is transformed: UTF-16, UTF-8, or UTF-32. The exact bytes comprising the BOM will be whatever the Unicode character `U+FEFF` is converted into by that transformation format. In that form, the BOM serves to indicate both that it is a Unicode file, and which of the formats it is in.

If you want to, just pass a string (which is binary in PHP) that contains the BOM. Example strings:

```
Bytes           PHP String          Encoding Form
-----           ----------          -------------
00 00 FE FF     "\0\0\xFE\xFF"      UTF-32, big-endian
FF FE 00 00     "\xFF\xFE\0\0"      UTF-32, little-endian
FE FF           "\xFE\xFF"          UTF-16, big-endian
FF FE           "\xFF\xFE"          UTF-16, little-endian
EF BB BF        "\xEF\xBB\xBF"      UTF-8
```

See http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html